# Gradle spring dependency management plugin and publishing the library

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

Im have my library, for help me with spring stuff, `build.gradle` looks like

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.7.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
}

publishing {
    // Default maven publish settings
}
```

When publishing, Gradle generates `.module` files, and then if the library is used by gradle, it prioritizes `.module` files over `.pom` files

The problem is that no dependencyManagement information is written to the `.module` file, and so when I try to use the library in another project, I get

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':shadowJar'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:.
     Required by:
         project : > project :database > ru.spliterash:spcore-spring-database-mongo:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:20220714.235637-1
```

I can solve this problem by disabling the generation of `.module` files, and gradle will have to use a pom file in which the version is written, but maybe if there is some more correct solution, because it seems to me that this is not entirely correct

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to the problem.

In new versions of gradle, this appeared as a built-in solution, and now spring dependency management plugin is not needed. In order to add a maven bom, it is enough just to write, and it will be correctly entered into the `module` file

```
dependencies {
    implementation(platform('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.7.0'))
    implementation(platform('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2021.0.2'))

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
}
```